# Cannot generate document from custom document shopware 6.4

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have followed instruction on adding new custom document type from [shopware docs for 6.4](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v/6.4/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/document/add-custom-document-type).

The only difference from above example is adding `$this->addDocumentBaseConfig($connection, $documentTypeId);` copied from [docs for 6.5](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/document/add-custom-document-type)

New document type show correctly in admin panel but I cannot generate this document.
Inside order when I click generate document, app sends request with body

```
{
    "config": {
        "custom": {},
        "documentNumber": "10004",
        "documentComment": "",
        "documentDate": "2023-05-09T09:33:38.545Z"
    },
    "referenced_document_id": null
}
```

on endpoint `POST /api/_action/order/65a3583a9bf543339c12ebf34a04b640/document/proforma`
where `proforma` is my custom document type

In response I get

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": "400",
            "code": "DOCUMENT__GENERATION_ERROR",
            "title": "Bad Request",
            "detail": "Unable to generate document. referencedDocumentId must not be null for documents of type proforma",
            "meta": {
                "parameters": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Why is that?
When I checked request for other document type, `invoice` for example, `referencedDocumentId` is set to `null` as well but document is generated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is thrown if your `document_base_config` has a set `referencedDocumentType` but you don't provide the `referenceDocumentId`.

Simply don't set the `referenceDocumentType` when creating the base config.

```php
private function addDocumentBaseConfig(Connection $connection, string $documentTypeId): void
{
    $defaultConfig = [
        'displayPrices' => true,
        'displayFooter' => true,
        'displayHeader' => true,
        // ...
        'referencedDocumentType' => self::TYPE, // <= remove this line
    ];
    
    // ...
}
```